# Google Calendar notifications during the event

Tags: google-calendar, notifications

How can I get a notification of non-all-day event **during** the event?

Say I need to get to the bank for 5 mins anytime between 15:00 and 16:00 and I want to be notified at 15:00, 15:20 and 15:40. However I want to see the event spanning from 15:00 to 16:00 in my calendar.